# Passing data between multiple Context Providers in React

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a couple of context providers (UserContextProvider & PostContextProvider). I need to use a value (user) from UserContextProvider inside PostContextProvider, how do I do this?

```
//user context

export const UserContext = React.createContext({ user: null});
export const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
 const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

 const getUser = async () => {
    ...fetch user data form the api
    setUser(response.data);
 }

 return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{props.children}</UserContext.Provider>;
}
```

```
//post context

export const PostContext = React.createContext({ post: null});
export const PostContextProvider = (props) => {
 const [post, setPost] = useState(null);

 const getUser = async () => {
    ...fetch post data form the api
    setPost(response.data);
 }

 return <PostContext.Provider value={post}>{props.children}</PostContext.Provider>;
}
```

```
// index.js
export default class Home extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <PostContextProvider>
      <UserContextProvider>
       {children}
      </UserContextProvider>
     </PostContextProvider>
   )
 }

}
```